# How to subclass the MatchObject in Python?

Tags: python

I have been playing around with regular expressions and was trying to subclass the MatchObject that is returned from re.search.

I have had no luck getting access to the MatchObject class.

I assume enter code herethat the actual type of this object is not called "MatchObject":

```
>>> re.search ("a", "a")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100427a58>
```

However, I am not able get access to this object:

```
import _sre

dir (_sre)
['CODESIZE', 'MAGIC', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'compile', 'copyright', 'getcodesize', 'getlower']

>>> dir(_sre.SRE_Match)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SRE_Match'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not gonna happen :)

```
>>> import re
>>> mo = re.search ("a", "a")
>>> mo_class = type(mo)
>>> mo_class
<type '_sre.SRE_Match'>
>>> class SubClass(mo_class):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type '_sre.SRE_Match' is not an acceptable base type
```

It's worth noting that you can always get access to the type of an object by calling `type(obj)` though.

Comment: What is going on? How is it implemented? Why do the docs lie to us about the class name? Lazy to rtfs :-)

Answer (score 0):

The class is accessible through `_sre._SRE_Match`. Don't ask me why.

Comment: How?  I tried but couldn't.

Comment: @ibonyun In more recent versions of Python, it's available as `re.Match`. (It's still not an acceptable base type.)